# Looping through all users in a server

Tags: python, discord.py

Here is my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, task
    
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '$')
    
@client.command(aliases=['au'])
async def all_users(ctx):
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            print(member)
```

(I did `client.run` after that just didn't show my token here)

The output when I run the command:

[image: OUTPUT]

It just outputs the ID of the bot twice (There are 3 people in that server)

What should I do to make it print all the users in the guild?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enable `Intents.members` like this before `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '$')` :

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
```

and update the `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '$')` to `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '$', intents=intents)`, so your final code would be:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, task
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '$', intents=intents)
    
@client.command(aliases=['au'])
async def all_users(ctx):
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            print(member)
```

Also you have to enable member intents in your application site in discord (something like discord.com/developers/applications/your_bot_id_here/bot):
[image: Enable member intents]

References:

[discord.Intents.members](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Intents.members)

Comment: @KushagraVijay could you accept the answer so other people can see that it works?